# Releasing Com Objects Doesnt Affect Memory Usage

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, arcgis, arcobjects

When I release com objects by Marshall.ReleaseComObject method, memory usage of application doesnt change. Instead of using Marshall.ReleaseComObject, using Garbage Collector (GC.Collect()) can release memory area of com objects but the UI is getting slow down.

So my question is, what is the best method to release com objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do is using ComReleaser or Marshal.ReleaseComObject methods. Calling GC.Collect method too much will cause to slow down of your application. Let GC do its job when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Athough a bit outdated (as from ArcGIS 10.0) the rules for releasing and how to do so are pretty well described on http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Releasing_COM_references/0001000004tm000000/.

There are two ways to do this. Either by using `Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject` or by the `ComReleaser`-class which essentially is a wrapper around the former. However you may have multiple references to the exact same com-object, which is why calling `ReleaseComObject` will not *finally* release the object, but simply decrease the internal reference-counter by one. Only when that counter is equal to zero the object will *actually* be released. See here for example:

```
var f1 = featureClass.GetFeature(1);
// retrieve the exact same feature again
var f2 = featureClass.GetFeature(1);
```

Although from a .NET-perspective `f1` and `f2` are comlpletely different objects, the underlying com-object is the same (assuming unique-instancing, which is out of the scope of this question). When calling `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on either `f1` or `f2`, you will only decrease the internal reference-counter for this com-object by one, leaving one reference alive.

`GC.Collect` however has no effect as it can´t handle *unmanaged* resources which com-objects are. The garbage-collector is only able to release *managed* resources. Calling `GC.Collect` will thus only - if at all - release the runtime-callable-wrapper, which is a managed wrapper around the unmanaged object. The latter however still exists in memory and is likely to produce a dead-leak.

Having said this the only way to *finally* release a com-objects is to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` in a loop until the reference-counter is zero.

```
while(Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myObject) > 0);
```

Afterwards you may or may not call `GC.Collect`. However I won´t suggest to do so, as the garbage-collector knows best when to release a mananed object. Forcing it to do so will at best work as expected, at worst however only mke your code slow without having any positive effect. GC is un-determinsitc process, you can´t *really* influence it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oApp);
oApp = null; // Set each COM Object to null
//
// After all of the COM objects have been released and set to null, do the following:
GC.Collect(); // Start .NET CLR Garbage Collection
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); // Wait for Garbage Collection to finish
```

Answer (score 0):

If object implement finalizer, call gc means put this object reference in finalization queue, means it doesnt release immediately.